# Understanding a Simple class with Magic Methods

Tags: php

I just started following a video series on OOP in PHP and have made the following class following one lecture. At first there was no `__get` and `__set`, because he showed us to how to deal with public variables. But for demonstrations sake the lecturer changed `public $postal_code` into `protected $_postal_code.` 
Basically what he showed was that he could change the original postal code that we set using

```
$adress->postal_code = "M422 3555";
```

into "`ADDED PROTECTED VALUE`" via this method

```
 protected function _postal_code_guess(){
        return 'ADDED PROTECTED VALUE';
```

Now the two main things I'm having trouble understanding is how do our `__get` and `__set` methods know what `$name` is? If I `echo $name` before anything in either the get or set methods it tells me it represents `postal_code`. But why is that? Where is it getting set that value?

The other thing I am a bit confused about is how the line `$output.=",".$this->postal_code;` is still working. Because we changed our original public `$postal_code` into protected `$_postal_code;`Doe-sent that mean we should change

```
$output.=",".$this->postal_code;
```

into

```
$output.=",".$this->_postal_code;
```

**TLDR**

1.How does our code know what `$name` is ?

2. Why are we still allowed to do `$output.=",".$this->postal_code;`, even when our variable was changed to `protected _postal_code`

Below is all the code

```
class Adress{

    public $country;
    public $province;
    public $city;
    public $adress;
    protected $_postal_code;

    // primary key of an adress
    protected $_adress_id;
    protected $_time_created;
    protected $_time_updated;

    function __get($name){

        if(!$this->_postal_code){
            $this->_postal_code = $this->_postal_code_guess();
        }

        // attempt to return a protected property by name
        $protected_property_name = "_".$name;
        if(property_exists($this,$protected_property_name)){
            return $this->$protected_property_name;
        }

        trigger_error("Undefined property via __get".$name);
        return null;    
    }

    function __set($name,$value){
        if('postal_code' == $name){
            $this->$name = $value;
            return;
        }

        trigger_error('Undefined or unallowed propert via __set()');

    }

    protected function _postal_code_guess(){
        return 'ADDED PROTECTED VALUE';
    }
    function display(){
        $output = '';

        $output.=$this->country;
        $output.="<br/>";
        $output.=$this->province;
        $output.=' '.$this->city;


  $output.=" ".$this->adress;
    $output.=",".$this->postal_code;
    return $output;
}
```

}

Here is the demo.php file where we run it

```
<?php
require 'index.php';
$adress = new Adress;
$adress->country = "Canada";
$adress->province = "Ontario";
$adress->city = "Toronto";
$adress->adress ="4324323 Bob Street";
$adress->postal_code = "M422 3555";
echo '<tt><pre>'.var_export($adress,TRUE).'</tt></pre>';
echo $adress->display();
echo '<h2>Test Protected Variables</h2>';
unset($adress->postal_code);
echo $adress->display();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [decent description of __get() and __set() magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) in the official PHP Manual.

`$this->postal_code` works only thanks to `__get()` method, which - in your example - dynamically tries to find a property with underscore removed. It's not any of default PHP behaviors, just specific to your code.

Comment: I think you are referring to the line $protected_property_name = "_".$name;. Before I ponder on this, may I ask how my code knows what $name, is?

Comment: This is internals of PHP. Every time when unexisting property is being used in your code, PHP runs your `__get()` method (if exists) and passes the name of requested property to it. This is a little magical, therefore "magic methods" :)

Comment: But how does it know to set postal code to this unexisting property. It could have been adress or city for that matter, how does it make the decision to map it to postal code?

Comment: Because your code explicitly hardcodes postal code behavior in those magic methods.

Comment: What line specifically sorry? I really have tried analyzing it

Comment: In your `__get()` and `__set()` methods, everything that has `postal_code` phrase in it :D

Comment: Oh.. So it just looks at what variable I reference inside of the _get and _set. So Could I have done the same for the other protected variables inside the same __get and __set?

Comment: Sure. You can have only one `__get()` and only one `__set()` obviously, so the only way to determine which property should be handled at the moment is this `$name` parameter. You can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: but if i add my other variables in other, how will name know what to refer too? Because NOW I could have _postal_code and some other variables?

Comment: Other variables in other? I don't know what you mean. There is always only one variable processed at time, even in lines like this: `$this->one = $this->two + $this->one + $this->three`. You can always learn through experimenting, just put `var_dump($name);` inside your `__get($name)` and `var_dump($name, $value);` inside your `__set($name, $value);`

Comment: From my understanding you are telling me that since in my get and set methods I am only referencing one protected variable ( _postal_code), it will automatically set $name to that. But what If I wanted to have some more protected variables inside? How would the engine know what to set name too?

Comment: @cresjoy would you have time for quick chat later today?

Comment: @cresjoy Just let me know once you are ready, I should be awake for like 5 more hours :D

Comment: Ok im here and in chat